# Laravel paginate returns blank object

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.1 and when I try to pass a paginator object to ajax it gets returned as a blank object.

The code I am using is:

```
$rows = $coupon->paginate(20);
return Response::json(array('success' => true, 'rows' => $rows));
```

If I do `dd($rows)` it outputs the expected result:

```
LengthAwarePaginator {#348 ▼
  #total: 1323
  #lastPage: 67
  #items: Collection {#368 ▶}
  #perPage: 20
  #currentPage: 1
  #path: "http://domain.app/admin/vouchers/search/"
  #query: []
  #fragment: null
  #pageName: "page"
}
```

**Why is this object coming through as blank?**

Comment: check with `$rows->toJson()`

Comment: But then how do I render the pagination links?

Comment: ... why would you render pagination links in json? Isn't that up to the user interface to handle, and not your api?

Comment: There are PHP functions to get the different pages like `next` or previous page. You have to check with JavaScript if there are more pages.

Comment: @SimonSvensson It's a search form.  On page load there are no results.  When the user clicks search, it brings up results using PHP/Ajax, but there can be up to 1300 results which would be unrealistic to get onto one page.  So I need to load the pagination from PHP/Ajax.  I can't think of another way?

Comment: I agree on using paging; it's just that it would be enough to send current page number, page size and total number of hits to the client; and the client could build the links itself. Then the client change change to whatever html element is needed (or your mobile app could use the same api and use other elements to trigger the paging).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same Issue when I added the Pagination object to a Laravel Model and sent it in the response, it was blank in the other side.

I fixed this by encoding it to Json and then back to an object. It seems that Laravel won't let you return a Pagination object if it's not alone in the response

Try this:

```
$rows = $coupon->paginate(20);
return Response::json( array( 'success'=>true,'rows'=> json_decode( $rows->toJson() ) ) );
```

Hope this works in your example too.